# Бот не запускается после команды в терминале

Tags: python, telebot

Вот весь код:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("API-ключ")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])

def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, '<b>Привет</b>', parse_mode='html')

    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Проблема в том, что после команды в терминале `python main.py` бот должен начинать работать, и в самом терминале не должно ничего выводить после этой команды, а мне, в свою очередь, в ответ приходит начальная строчка спустя 1 секунду (там где путь к файлу, после которого всё пишется в терминале), и, соответственно, бот не запускается и не реагирует на команды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте чтобы отступы были такие же как и в коде ниже, а так же крайне рекомендую добавить конструкцию `if __name__=="__main__"` в Ваш код, пример тоже ниже:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет")

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stope=True, interval=0)
```

Если Вы уверны что всё сделали правильно то сделайте слудущие действия:

***1.*** **Откройте консоль**

***2.*** **Введите комманду `pip3 uninstall telebot`** - Она удалит модуль `telebot` (также не забудьте подтвердить действия удаления модуля введя `Y` когда Вас об этом попросит в консоли)

***3.*** **Введите комманду `pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI`** - Она установит правильный модуль(иногда возникают ошибки из за неправильной установки модуля `telebot`)

***4.*** **Введите комманду `python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip`** - Она обновит пакетный менеджер `pip`

После всех проделаных действий попробуйсте перезапустить свой скрипт и у Вас всё должно начать работать! В ином случаи оповистите меня об этом в комментарии под ответом и я постараюсь Вам помочь!

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, ошибка была, как я понял в кавычках)

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог, то будьте добры поставьить галочку слева возле ответа, тем самым Вы поможете мне и другим кто столкнёться с данной проблемой